# To to pass entire value of JQquery to controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid-asp.net

I want to pass the variable grid to a method(controller)

Here is my ajax code:

```
function SaveReorderPriority(){

var partnerId = $("#partnerDropDownList").val();
var isoCountryCd = $("#cntryDropDownList").val();
var partnerSystem = $("#partnerSysDropDownList").val();
var grid = $("#critCombiMapGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');

if (partnerId != "" && isoCountryCd != "" && partnerSystem!="") {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../../C3Web/CriteriaCombinationMapping/Index',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { partnerId: partnerId, isoCountryCd: isoCountryCd, partnerSystem: partnerSystem, grid : grid},
```

Here is my method from Controller. Please help me to pass the variable grid to this method parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(String grid, string partnerId, string isoCountryCd, string partnerSystem)
{
```

Comment: `grid` will be an array of complex objects, so for a start you need `data: JSON.stringify({ partnerId: partnerId, .... , grid : grid }),` and add the `contentType: 'application/json',` option. And then `grid` in the POST method needs to be `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is a model matching the properties your grid is serializing

Answer (score 0):

`var grid = jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data')` returns an array

you can pass the array by converting it into string like so:

```
grid.toString()

data: { grid : grid.toString(), partnerId: partnerId, isoCountryCd: isoCountryCd, partnerSystem: partnerSystem},
```

and then split the string back to an array on the server:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(String grid, string partnerId, string isoCountryCd, string partnerSystem)
{
   string[] gridData = grid.Split(',');
```

**EDIT**

You had `grid` **first** and i missed it, so I added it again in my first answer.

You are passing `grid` **last**:

```
data: { partnerId: partnerId, isoCountryCd: isoCountryCd, partnerSystem: partnerSystem, **grid : grid**},
```

But you have declared it **first**:

```
public ActionResult Index(String grid, string partnerId, string isoCountryCd, string partnerSystem)
```

I would change the order just to avoid any confusion

Comment: IM getting an error upon doing that one. seems like it didnt reach the method.PartnerId param is null upon checking.

Comment: I've edited my answer because in your post the order of parameters is wrong

Comment: Here is the error:An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in C3_Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: var grid compose of 3 columns, this might be the reason of error in controller method. it was not able to convert into array.